# separate red green blue and alpha values from rgba string

Tags: php

I am separating Red, Green, Blue and Alpha values of rgba color values using php the code work fine when i have integer value but get only decimal part even have a floating values

this is the code

```
$myRGBString = "rgba(132,15,153,0.7)";
sscanf($myRGBString, 'rgba(%d,%d,%d,%d)', $red, $green, $blue, $alpha);
```

Above Code return aplha value 0 not 0.7 how can i get floating values of alpha

Answer (score 0):

Use `%f` instead of `%d` for the alpha value.

```
C:\Users\Niet>php -r "sscanf('rgba(132,15,153,0.7)','rgba(%d,%d,%d,%f)',$r,$g,$b,$a); var_dump($r,$g,$b,$a);"
int(132)
int(15)
int(153)
float(0.7)
```